# When I am running terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am creating ec2 instance and this is my main.tf file

```
variable "aws_key_pair" {

  default = "~/aws/aws_keys/terraform-ec2.pem"

}

provider "aws" {

  region  = "us-east-1"

  version = "~>2.46"

}

resource "aws_security_group" "http_server_sg" {

  name   = "http_server_sg"

  vpc_id = "vpc-c5f40fb8"

  ingress {

    from_port   = 80

    to_port     = 80

    protocol    = "tcp"

    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }

  ingress {

    from_port   = 22

    to_port     = 22

    protocol    = "tcp"

    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }

  egress {

    from_port   = 0

    to_port     = 0

    protocol    = -1

    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }

  tags = {

    name = "http_server_sg"

  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "http_server" {

  ami                    = "ami-0947d2ba12ee1ff75"

  key_name               = "terraform-ec2"

  instance_type          = "t2.micro"

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.http_server_sg.id]

  subnet_id              = "subnet-1169c14e"

  connection {

    type        = "ssh"

    host        = self.public_ip

    user        = "ec2_user"

    private_key = file(var.aws_key_pair)

  }

  provisioner "remote_exec" {

    inline = [

      "sudo yum install httpd -y",

      "sudo service httpd start",

      "echo Welcome to virtual server setup by terraform , IP address ${self.public_dns} | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html"

    ]

  }

}
```

When I  am running : terraform apply      I am getting following error

---

Could not load plugin

Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".

Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate

resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,

don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.

Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your

configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the

requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".

Failed to instantiate provisioner "remote_exec" to obtain schema: unknown

provisioner "remote_exec"

But I have already done terraform init   and when I am running terraform validate I am getting same above error

Answer (score 2):

It's "remote-exec" ...